# Can't select the drop-down option

Tags: java, selenium

Using the select method I can't select the dropdown

I tried using normal and findelement method and also index selection method

Here am using input value in different file

```
click(driver,"id",prop.getProperty("state"));
click(driver,"xpath",prop.getProperty("voption"));
```

and 
Index selection method
and

```
Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
drpCountry.selectByVisibleText("ANTARCTICA");
```

**Expected result :**
need to click the dropdown

**Actual result :**
"stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"
it showing error message like this

Comment: Share your HTML code ?

Comment: Also, share your error stack trace.

Comment: HTML : <select id="state"class="txt-search-input">....</select>
 ERROR MEASSAGE: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Post the full error stack trace in the post instead of just the message. Want to know on which line/element you are getting the error.  Also, post the code of the click method.

Comment: Please share the complete DOM structure for us to verify and post the relevant code. With the error you have received, we can only gauge that probably the element isn't visible yet when the code was being run ( I am only assuming ).

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the `WebElement` first, then select by visible text.

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("state"));
new Select(dropDown).selectByVisibleText("ANTARCTICA");
```

If this does not work, but you **dont get** the `StaleElementReferenceException` change the selection option to `selectByIndex()` or `selectByValue()`.

If you get `StaleElementReferenceException` pointing to line with `driver.findElement(...)` it means that something on your page has changed so some kind of wait mechanism should be introduced. In such case I suggest to locate the **dropDown** using `FluentWait`.